# Show/Hide divs, "one by one" and "all at once"

Tags: javascript, toggle, togglebutton

I'm using this to show/hide some divs, at the end I have a button to show the divs one by one.

How can I have a second button to show/hide all of them at once without messing too much with the HTML?

Basically each div contains an input field, so the user clicks the "Add one more" button to get an extra field. By default, all fields are hidden so I need a button to show them all at once (I have 14 divs to show/hide).

Any help will be appreciated.

**Javascript**

```
var counter = 0;
var numBoxes = 3;
function toggle4(showHideDiv) {
       var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv + counter);
       if(ele.style.display == "block") {
              ele.style.display = "none";
       }
       else {
              ele.style.display = "block";
       }
       if(counter == numBoxes) {
                document.getElementById("toggleButton").style.display = "none";
       }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
         <div id="box1" style="display: none;">First</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
         <div id="box2" style="display: none;">Second</div
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
         <div id="box3" style="display: none;">Third</div
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<input id="toggleButton" type="button" value="Add one more!" onclick="counter++; toggle4('box');">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic functionality, though it needs some refinement:

```
var d = document,
    table = d.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    divs = table.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    toggle = d.getElementById('toggleButton'),
    allToggle = d.getElementById('allToggle'),
    count = 0;

function toggles(){    
    var elem = divs[count];
    elem.style.display = 'block';

    count++;
}

toggle.onclick = function(){
    toggles();
};

allToggle.onclick = function(){
    if (allToggle.getAttribute('data-show') == 1){
        for(var i=0,len=divs.length;i<len;i++){
            divs[i].style.display = 'none';
            allToggle.setAttribute('data-show',0);
            allToggle.value = 'Show all';
        }
    }
    else {
        for(var i=0,len=divs.length;i<len;i++){
            divs[i].style.display = 'block';
            allToggle.setAttribute('data-show',1);
            allToggle.value = 'Hide all';
        }
    }
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ABnUS/2/).

The above based on the following HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
         <div id="box1" style="display: none;">First</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
         <div id="box2" style="display: none;">Second</div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px;">
         <div id="box3" style="display: none;">Third</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<input id="toggleButton" type="button" value="Add one more!" />
<input id="allToggle" type="button" value="Show all" />​
```

Comment: Weird; I could've sworn I posted a working version. Sorry about that! Updated with *really-working* code and demo. =/

Comment: Sorry, but your "Add one more!" simply shows one and if you click again it will hide the previous and show the next one, I'm trying to "Add one more!" - meaning that if I click the button I will show the next div but preserving the previous one (it will remain visible). Your latest demo works perfect but not as expected.

Comment: Oh, really? Ah. I thought that was an omission on your part, sorry. Give me a moment or two and that'll be removed! =) **Edited**, any closer?

Comment: Glad to hear it! And, honestly, you're quite welcome; I'm glad to have been of help =)

Comment: Update: don't work on wordpress (on the admin side) reason: unknown - Thanks any way

Comment: It is more suitable generally to toggle between 'none' and '' (empty string) so that visible elements adopt their default or inherited display rather then be set to a possibly inappropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

have a button with a function that selects all of the divs by a class (that you'll have to add) and hides/shows them. If you just want one button you'll have to remember your state, which in the example below I do with a global.

```
<button id="showhideall">

$(document).ready(function(){

var allshowing = true;

$("#showhideall").click(function(){
    alert(allshowing);
    if(allshowing){
        $(".foo").hide();
        allshowing=false;            
    } else {
        $(".foo").show();
    }
});
}​);​
```

Comment: Yhea! that sounds like the solution, but can you give me an example ?

Comment: can you explain your code a bit more, Where the box1, box2 and box3 are included on your code ?

Comment: @Colleen, I think you should make it clear you're not using pure JavaScript. Other people should know they would need to use JQuery for this to work

Comment: @Christian I had that thought and then dismissed it... guess I shouldn't have :) Thanks for pointing it out! OP, the html is just how you have it, except that you'd need to add class "foo" to each of your divs, and add the button.

Answer (score -1):

```
var counter = 0;
var numBoxes = 3;
function toggle4(showHideDiv) {
       var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv + counter);
       if(ele.style.display == "block") {
              ele.style.display = "none";
       }
       else {
              ele.style.display = "block";
       }
       if(counter == numBoxes) {
                document.getElementById("toggleButton").style.display = "none";
       }
}

function toggle3(contentDiv) {
        if (contentDiv.constructor == Array) {
                for(i=0; i < contentDiv.length; i++) {
                     toggle2(contentDiv[i]);
                }
        }
        else {
               toggle2(contentDiv);
        }
}

function toggle2(showHideDiv) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);

    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";

      }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";

    }
}

<input id="toggleButton" type="button" value="Show me the money!" onclick="counter++; toggle4('box');">

<input type="button" value="Press me to toggle all 3 DIVs" onClick="toggle3(['box1', 'box2', 'box3']);">
```